# Drupal 7: When using the Features module and the database (e.g content type) is different than the matching Features component

Tags: features

Drupal 7: When using the Features module and the database (e.g content type) is different than the matching Features component (e.g the same content type) what is used when viewing this component within the Drupal webapp?

Answer (score 1):

If the Feature is overridden, then what you have stored in the database is what Drupal will be using until you revert either the whole feature, or the item in question (such as your View for example).

As an example, if you have an exported View and you make some changes, it will be read from the database. If you either update or revert your Feature, then it will go back to being read from code.